# Differential equation of all surfaces with z axis as axis of revolution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

> Find the Differential equation of all surfaces with z axis as axis of revolution?

How to find the generic equation form. For cone with z axis and origin as vertex, equation is $x^2+y^2=z^2 \tan^2 \alpha, \alpha$ being semi-vertical angle of cone.
But how to generalise this?

It is actually a solved problem in my text book. Generic form is taken directly as $z=f(x^2+y^2)$. How did he arrive at this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With $z=f(u)$ where $u=x^2+y^2$ then 
$$\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial x}=\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial u}\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x} ~~~~~~,~~~~~ \dfrac{\partial z}{\partial y}=\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial u}\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial y}$$
or
$$p=\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial u}2x ~~~~~~,~~~~~ q=\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial u}2y$$
gives the differential equation $\color{blue}{py-qx=0}$.

Comment: Sir i am not asking on how to form DE. I am asking how to get general form of such surfaces. $z=f(x^2+y^2)$

Comment: It has a simple intuition. for all plane $z=k$, the intersection plane with such surface is a (some) circle(s).

Comment: Got it sir, thank you

Comment: You did not need to accept my answer. I got the problem wrong.

Comment: Sir u clarified it in comment section. You are patiently clarifying my doubts.. Tq.

Comment: You are welcome. and thanks.

Comment: Sir can you pls have a look at this? -https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2887999/surface-integral-formed-by-paraboloid-of-revolution-and-cylinder